# How does string interpolation work in bash?

Tags: bash

I am trying to interpolate a parameter's value in a string. Let me present a simple example for generality and simplicity.

```
size="40"
#Yes, variable size is a string
echo "Total Bytes $size"
#^ works fine: outputs Total Bytes: 40
echo "Total Bytes: $size bytes"
#outputs  bytesBytes: 40
#The string " bytes" is inserted at the beginning overwriting the other string- why?
```

I have tried multiple variations of the these commands but none seem to work leading me to believe that I am making some classic noob mistake. 
Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You saved it with `CRLF` line endings. Didn't you? Confirm with `file your_script_file`

Comment: @anishsane are you going to make that an answer?

Comment: try `dos2unix your_script_file` or `sed -i $'s/\r//' your_script_file`

Comment: Oh! In my code, size is actually being set by a curl command piped by awk. I suppose the newline slipped in because of that. Is there some function equivalent to a trim in bash then?

Comment: Your Linux is behaving funny (it might be an office prank..), try the same code here: http://www.compileonline.com/execute_bash_online.php. It works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have saved the file with `CRLF` line endings.

try `dos2unix your_script_file` if your distro has it.
Else this is your solution: `sed -i $'s/\r//' your_script_file`

I guess your script is obtained from `curl`, which is a [dangerous practice](http://www.google.com/search?q=piping+curl+to+bash+is+dangerous). However, I will not go into those details for now.

You can simply pipe `curl` output through `tr -d '\r'` for getting the correct script what you want.

Comment: My variable is actually being set as:  
size=$(curl -sI $URL | grep Content-Length | awk '{print $2}'). The solution therefore couldn't get rid of the endings slipping in implicitly by the code. How do I get rid of that? Something like a trim?

Comment: Piped the trim using your suggestion: size=$(curl -sI $URL | grep Content-Length | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d '\r'). Works now. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I know this is old, but it's simpler to avoid generating the newline in the first place. `awk '{printf "%s", $2}'` instead of using `tr` afterward.